# Magento category thumbnails do not upload

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I spent all day today trying to get Magento to accept category tuhmbnail uploads, but nothing I've done works.

I can neither delete nor upload any thumbnails for any product categories in Magento 1.9.0.1

I've tried flushing the cache, reindexing, recompiling, disable cache and compiling, the works. The exact same setup works on my local machine but not on the server. There are no error messages or traces in any of the logs I've looked at. The permissions on my media folder and its subfolders and files are 777. They're relatively small images and I have the newest version 14,0,0,145 of Abode flash installed in Chrome, Firefox and IE on Windows 8.

Every time I attempt to upload or remove a thumbnail image I am met with a success message from Magento but nothing changes.

Please let me know if I'm not providing enough details and thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried configuring an item manually and then exporting it in case there are some subtle differences, for example in folder names?

Comment: I've create a new category from scratch with the same results. Exporting the category to CSV shows that all products have _media_is_disabled set to 1. Could that be affecting the category thumbnail upload? Product thumbnail uploads are working fine.